# How to start MySQL server automatically with application start?

Tags: c#, mysql, xampp

How can I start MySQL server automatically with C# WPF application start? I am using xampp. I want to start xampp and then MySQL automatically when the app starts, how to achieve it? I tried this:

```
ServiceController controller = new ServiceController();

controller.MachineName = ".";
controller.ServiceName = "mysql";

// Start the service
controller.Start();
```

but it is not working as it says that MySQL service does not exist.

Is this a good way how to do it or is there another way how to start xampp and MySQL automatically with app start so the user does not need to start it each time on his own?

Comment: Do you have installed MySql? If yes could you look at the Services applet and check what is the real service name?

Comment: `How can I start MySQL server automatically with C# WPF application start` why? It should already be running. What would be stopping this that you would then need to start it?

Comment: I have xampp installed, I cant find the MySql service in my pc but it is working after starting from xampp. It is not already running, I need to start it from xampp.

Comment: Turn it on from xampp then look at your running services to find the correct name. Chances are it's probably called mysqld (d for daemon)

Comment: it is mysql but I dont know why its not working

Comment: What OS is your server running on?